# how to pop back to the previous fragment in Java Android

Tags: java, android

so basically I am trying to remove the deprecation any advices.
on how to roll back to the previous fragment.

[image]

this is  what i tried but everything is deprecated. is there any way to perform the back press with not Deprecated code

note: this method is deprecated on the Fragment class only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically these onOptionsItemSelected() has been deprecated for Fragment class only. (still available for Activity class)

so the substitute is to provide a menuProvider as follows
note: as I have used this menu provider in a lot of classes I seperate it to reuse it.

```
public class MenuProviderManager implements MenuProvider {
    private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public MenuProviderManager(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

in your "FRAGMENT" you can do as follows

```
private void setMenuOptions() {
        MenuProviderManager menuProvider = new MenuProviderManager(getParentFragmentManager());
        MenuHost menuHost = getActivity();
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(menuProvider, getViewLifecycleOwner(), Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
    }
```

now in you this function has to be called from somewhere I used the onViewCreated(). Because I wanted to be sure that the menu is not created unless the view has it should be on. is created.

Answer (score 2):

You could update your code like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` does the "magic" and will return to the previous fragment.

Comment: is there any other way without the whole method cause it is deprecated i mean, onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) is deprecated, and the return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); is also deprecated. any other solution? 
I will try this one and get back to u? 

I appreciate your time Ars

Comment: I'm not certain why you're seeing that it is deprecated... I'm using Android Studio Giraffe  2022.3.1 Patch 4 with a `compileSdk` in the build.gradle of level 33 and I'm not seeing the strike-through code. Perhaps right-click and add to your question what the context menu has to say.

Answer (score 0):

Using in your Activity onBackPressed Method

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
 
    val count = supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: deprecated methods in Fragment class in Java
see solution below